# identities property of squaring functor?

Tags: category-theory

From page 31 of [The algebra of programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013507245X) :

> Next, consider the squaring functor $()^2: Fun \leftarrow Fun$ defined
>   by
>
> $$ A^2 = \{(a, b) | a \in A, b \in B\} \\ f^2(a, b) = (f a, f b) $$

Functors are required to preserve identities and composition:

$$
F(id_A) = id_{FA} \\
F(f \circ g) = Ff \circ Fg
$$

The second property is easy:

$$
(f \circ g)^2 (a, b) = ((f\circ g) (a), (f\circ g) b) \\
(f^2 \circ g^2) (a, b) = f^2 (g (a), g (b)) = ((f\circ g) (a), (f\circ g) (b))
$$

But I can't figure out how the squaring functor preserve the identity property. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have worked it out:

$$
id^2 (a, b) = (id(a), id(b)) = (a, b) = id_{A^2} (a, b)
$$